# enable multiple modules for same namespace

Tags: magento2, installation, command-line

I am installing a few modules one by one into my magento 2 application.  Can we enable all modules in the same namespace with one command?

Right now I am using:

```
php bin/magento module:enable Vendor_MyModule1
php bin/magento module:enable Vendor_MyModule2
php bin/magento module:enable Vendor_MyModule3
```

Is there a way I can do this with a wildcard?

```
php bin/magento module:enable Vendor_*
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You cannot use wildcards but you can enable all of them from one command like this:

```
php bin/magento module:enable Vendor_MyModule1 Vendor_MyModule2 Vendor_MyModule3
```

Comment: this is definitely an improvement

Answer (score 13):

**Short answer: Yes, you can.**

But it is *nix command trick, Magento 2 does not support it by default as [Marius](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/122358/18821) answer.

You can execute the following command and it can do what you want.

```
php bin/magento module:status | grep VendorName_ | grep -v List | grep -v None | grep -v -e '^$'| xargs php bin/magento module:enable
```

Cheers.

Answer (score 8):

You can use the the `--all` flag to enable all available modules

```
 php bin/magento module:enable --all
```

This of course is if you don't mind enabling all modules.  Tested in magento 2.1.x

Comment: Might be the way to go ... if you want to enable "most" then you can exec this ... then run Disable whta you dont need before you hit upgrade

Answer (score 0):

In case you have copied an entire namespace directory(ies) and want Magento to install all those at one shot then do the following :

php bin/magento setup:upgrade

This way you don't have to mention all modules names.

Comment: This is just perfect if you want to install magento with a lot of custom modules on a empty database. _<sequence> _  is just so bad with that...

Comment: `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` this won't enable any previously disabled module.  `setup:upgrade` is required after placing extensions dir. So first the extension has to be in `app/code/` and then enabling these extensions by `module:enable` then lastly running  `module:enable`

Answer (score 0):

**Another way would be:**

- Open `app/etc/config.php`
- That file returns an array of modules with the module name as key and `1` or `0` as value.

  - `1` indicates enabled
  - `0` indicates disabled
- You can find the modules that you want to disable and set their respective value to `0`.
- Here's an example:

  ```
  <?php
  return [
      'modules' => [
          ...
          ...
          'Vendor_MyModule1' => 0,
          'Vendor_MyModule2' => 0,
          'Vendor_MyModule3' => 0,
          ...
          ...
  ```
- After that, open terminal and go to your magento root directory.

  ```
  cd /path/to/your/magento/root/folder
  ```
- Finally, run setup upgrade command:

  ```
  php bin/magento setup:upgrade
  ```

Comment: i will recommend  @Toan Nguyen answer.